# Download small ZFS formatted image

Tags: filesystems, zfs

I don't run Linux myself, so I'm the odd one out here, but I have hopelessly been searching for a small image file that contains ZFS (e.g. ZFS formatted media).

I like to implement ZFS recognition in my software.  No full exploration (not now anyway), but just being able to detect that the image (or physical device) is formatted with ZFS, to alert the user of that fact.

Can anybody direct me to a place where I can download such a file ?  Maybe an installation of something or ... ?

Comment: You don't run Linux yourself, but I guess you don't run Solaris either (which is where ZFS comes from)?

Comment: No I run Windows and work on my Windows software program.  I sadly know very very little about Unix/Linux and the different versions etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a ZFS image created with:

```
truncate -s 64M pool
losetup /dev/loop0 pool
zpool create test-pool /dev/loop0
echo test > /test-pool/test-file.txt
zpool export test-pool
bzip2 -9 pool
```

Which is probably the smallest you can get. Here uuencoded:

``````````````````````````````````````
begin 644 pool.bz2
M0EIH.3%!629365I`^4$``HG_____________________________________
M________X$9?``!]%`DJBD5$`**4)*2!0E0$HJ*(I4``BJ0HJ2J%4`4*A*%(
ME!54)`1(15"E$I00(`0`HI44$"5$E`*`4``%!(`%"$%%)42445544HI212@"
M$**`HJBB@*E0`E4A5`%%!0DF``F``)@`````````````````````````````
M````````DP`$P`!,`````````````````````````````````````$F``F``
M)@`````````````````````````````````````DP`$P`!,`````````````
M````````````````````````!-51!`3(`$T:&@`$S1,`F)H::::&AHT#4PR:
M!HT-"8&@3:F3$P!,F:3$U-A-,`F$83!,0R::8)A4\&C330:&&BH%*D@@$$9&
M31B::&@F$R,)H:39`:I^AID:AZGJ;4V4VJ>U'HAM4],C$T:8J/]5/TQ09Z4V
M4VT%-Z*GM#U&J>GZIF1H:>JGM)-X4\U-)I^E/4PGZGHC3U-I--I,%3K$X%F=
MJ[-H3_2^Q=FSNV/4LSLV=Z1_S>.:]LOW$]$FJTIPCM3<-EF-NPSLS6?BMW33
M=`\<ZEUKLFJK@N1<-OW`:$T,F=H:&A+HUQK!M/<_%T)I:30W#,X389+38LK"
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M]+`_-L$>+JQ4ZBK$.'8+)9,G*KC5Q%^/.O'!MP\<T:II4PD/PSPDZF<#/L3-
M1QS%)S)8*Z8M8RCBF!]M819EZ*R6BK#KV(N2L"LRQ1:K`.-,6O9[)TU6+)<X
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M%HI>M-8S.M-:K4N&U+_1&:PL6D-59U[!B:`R6K6[%9Z[^-6LM.+5EO=CVP[V
M/V!KS1K"<>KLE=5*P;`:=.`G<W=7#LE<.]2]4T&W87IQNFQ:ST;<#:/#/#UP
M\[VTJ\_7AAS!<&HX5S#VE6^1G7(61>SN2CH"XIZ=FJWCMGLW;6\?P-XSEY)_
M"-C/`M9X-G99]X83TPVP]:M%Y5YLUJCI+"[!:%,+T2\LS.+O'K"R9,JR>1$8
M+*I@X-6_F2.M6%=;.%9#BV']:VRR'"6#]1?AG<7Y,;8\4TEN5A8,*8.?N+<?
M<X-<8W06XG1,*:C9*^C/[6NP8/NL&O:=J#E*V-[X<G6,WLV#N<K>S"8,&#UC
M!BJN`5FFS)EE@,X]0Y!Z=L;X(]@T6@-E4X>I9V!2A;F9!E5FF6609)6['8O&
M.V.!9G\-83UPRS5F#"KK'3MRW,[H-$9["=E,6,Z(870C"IP-U(ZE7[5VL:-M
MUNYY*JOW7D&H,\=YN7II."9J[NQ4ZNM4:,YF82V`Z2VX]*ZU<A<A</9Z:K`:
M5K4WD^3<+#HQE;&F:NW-E66];-A#/#3;ZZT>/&2K=#8#.,E@BQ80Z>R4V(U*
ML1D\FL+E5_(SML7C+/<`TCU]7;,GBUB6SNL8SH;*QG8#:,:V=>5FLR6O/$S(
MLP^&-65R$PAD&@S3"Y(86LY:9ADLPW(R#7&6.Z4W3K1VMEG,L+&853(M(8V%
MASJP<N\=5RU6_,580U5XU=FN/+WMW:;B\O=/:\6V&\MR/UZRK=C,,46`X8<5
M<XXEMV#<#>VB-K+;,MJ#+/J3$>+B?,=&T-JK!J'UE@<@<^M:K-5HC?G`JRCF
MV0\:X1V3`FY&QIN&>G/K?C@J<U-&6"W8SS)7(#:-A87<E91QTWRM!B-:<6K]
MD<-,T^@KBINFI,M<..T?QN$?QW?!F'[]/>#J'PIQ[&5T,]--U9U<XTVW&-66
M'@G'6S?[VYO6&H3A#EXZQWUS]6^JSU8LJPHPCH%L,\;MT[^>W)T:\K:ZZ]TI
M:[!;LL\G3V#\,P=PIZ(=M=FYILTL\P9&UM.N2FRE9K!%BKG)KRNC&E,)ZQF>
M%E9*9)H3+-#FUY&V:N_;-D7RS:JU&8O,U8+7(Q/36_<N.@&_M&T)+B*:K$82
MK@U8#GJJZ&8T<1,&:GC70UD&`T1QXS4\.\`\7,UK6!J&K'W36?MK0NF6(U+5
M6>S+-8N6L65@.ZMY>FLK=#96I=BN3>++\>/7K2M1BPN\TPL9A:$Z:V(T:F5F
M)K#&8L9@,'_S!+ZTT*[9="T&@,+2=*QFUF%=$_9LYY%@.Z77M1S;19E@TAM*
M<1.Y7&#P,X>G'CHW"4U)J,H[*[59+,[>SKA&K.8&<9V@5BSJ]RR3@IBQ8N,F
M1@K.K//)/6#&JX]_->`:5J5QC58TT*8%[AF9V9L6%,]@-W-@_SF25Z*XMPF%
MKIIMFK6496Q9./C1'D+RR,A:TK-8L[!@P&$PF#"8T\NTV#%UCBW5,]5E9'!#
M&5L)IC&WS7G&-!Z=X4<@,U,6@SL[.Y&91Q+8#$T5>':<R4O=3"K2<PKN,UZ;
M%FFQE84TV#T"LDR39C?.<IT5H5SJP-9:J-6K,N.6`W!U5W^M9UIF$YIT=65P
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M(XI9K2366'-\-C'F7-,OS[7<Z:FL#`Q5BPL70L+:6!H6_6TLUIL6>K^>[BW[
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MP'I9@]K-&*MY.4;B9)7*T\J]C._/8ST`U#;UYNKN0_L?5;=ZAVV>X>AIT=V-
M.WC>SI;F;UDW8[Z-HJN8IT=>!F2?@KU$T)]2;-Y)VZP'_-,PZ&=_F:])J71C
M0G4UOK^0=X5GKG'J'GIL%;^X]KM"?PTVC%M)C/0M.:#!@Q=UKG'A)U*N"%TU
ML%^@;!VYR5-:5X9Q35O4UJ3/;4:45YH?WMQ/]V6SS]335P-ZZ86Y9&>3KIST
M_#Q4O830MM.%I@\],&8:4S,+RS%PM=?9V9>:G3,;:<$Z::@Y>>3LK.\(P5Y:
M=0ZO(\BPN)IBQM(8U/[IDIWF;5NYDNK&\8VHPFL,+7F5L9__#+5^.WH[M/33
MW[Y3OE[&[]:5/7#5GF')3+/`#*Q9+";ZLEW&=<F@FZF='!#`9WEV9DF$-2L6
MJU1@-6YHV`S4P&$V$SEB-$85@.[V%,6"SS`=S8E-:K7JR(T,&O&!958K"6LQ
M96H&_1DL1D&*N%5MH[A:%6@L(_`OE1BTV:C5F%YV;+*MIJMS9ELE@JU&$VXU
MK(TV>PE69A-9I#(K)>58JL[7LJN16+*SF1GMD&4FM8@;N8JUVI8J-M:C0G+,
MHBLE/A7?'P[W]/5LTM-7,,D_1L.-L%'F:N#91N*M^\NY@Q2Q9QFL]7?WK;._
M?L.]G`.SLT3D+X%YQ8+,9.;EOQD%<DUG:3O.4KB;"O-VX8BRXS%)<C+"'34X
MIY&XLK0S$Y*PE7/MR,8F5NYMJ9)[\8'85Z!C4L_OABJNAFNQ7M&$EFPIT=A3
M'"G^3:L:[)@.Y/LN-OBLMHX#1MY=@LUY@L6$8&[M.5CGK&57`MNN@+?VHM/7
MOA/,\BRM.<P/8,6[83Q[-P%6>RRJXJ[A?'9'\KN_P/67J6T'1U8*<=+?/?7M
M;8/0/+OY7:[JQ\R_8>[>IAMK=#\LQ#9CF+5LE.WU,&$K"8287ME^@R0\\PU'
M57.K,WM7265K/W5J+,76-^,4^L-.=N&1$Z[G/@C)<I+`9QBUE<-QMHG37EK(
MY2P7^Q85\FP.+8=RP'27XUDZ!8+:7OR]"DROT[.[RPK,L/@F562PUKFKOMHW
MMW-NP=,W+..WS5NM&A:`X.MH]Y./KU3E55H+:57!COEC7%7.#F!\&W+_4?MC
M\@U5:MA<Y&W,1E&(P7YB]C97LV)^'5^]'+W7#GK,7-V"6%A+25@-1P;%BYEB
MJ<\&"GG;DYE5[]F+C*69&5@+E[%AA,&#!@56@P'F*S5E:([4P9E;V8L57D!P
M<L9L[=6E62'5#!7Y1A`A:4TIJ3(EH3SX]%,BF[K"&HY&;=X&GMVFU&@QF"76
MVU:0R)P,PF88UB.*5A-O3,NOMJ,\:;!\Q9V3LUX/_=>/6=J!KU:C(/<BM@,)
M76C,K*,&,K@Z9IE1J586(PO^UU#T%O5A8,]T,XU92;%JEO%<C3H1E5JV>_"/
M(O%JR#H6"MA-2F%B-JRL57$6-Q-P[YBOSLZNWJV@QL],!P@YUT+T#:6V;]RC
MM5.AN:5J7'*W%B2PIO;&>`&6X-I#*,DX*QO>3"F$K"W32'2*[I>4&`]X."*X
M@:-,].$F,[,85RUA56V5P2MG3@I<X-$9!]FT!R-M&JKFBM-FF_L):C83&W\P
MM^QF-S;`9FX?*5@^$\-=3]Q@^XWKGW$/VJWPWSA;J:X<=$KML[%VML[U-R4W
M%YAWI^%7)M"ZIRDK1AR"M:5N'(M53"Q;:Z*9;P<=Y5J1J6I8C0X-@N(&+QQ9
M[*K",6$Z25C3.PGR1@%Q%,'$C.QIQU8)QLPG*#;S>V2J7YV`]LUQS*O?W%3-
M?\,+/.&<.[G,MWJ8*OY[9C.R#=C;5NA_590N!5@/W>/>/9'OV$,HW(\I7G*_
M3=/>"KZ+WEW:]Q5FO<N<FT]7<*WK_D\D[MK-XVGX5[=>FO-.@=BZQUSB-X.O
MJ;.FUG1,)M[W;O5\*:@S#!JU8#Q%I6>-W&>-<,+7,*C]`T+V$8C?+F"Y:KI7
M]]JHTJP=NR7GF#[M9XR+WBQ!K58=0C,63\%97=],J\PVZK2M$<]9G(,[(R,F
M"PLF&NZ8O9O8OG,F_;#HHU;*G]T]B[-_D^E/K5G:$X]R$WH\)7C'L7^+_-6D
M.3KD3$G"UN;L+6N-E8V+E'*RN-<<[H\V\^["=A.(JZ][BT7"=<8,,,,,&##0
M7$+,S,KG)L9_$YY_/-S*[[,\P?<K0&Z'(N@LC6K(-]9*OZ'`/U#GQE+[@T&,
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MU;1=1;"W3%T"ZY?6^IMD\*/GZLSN%'>1S8TAQS/;16U8.9O`S:.QGUF8?1'L
M1I6JK"YT81;:8#8V%Q8^'6E-W3HQNZ<</ES1'PIH3&O&["VE,BTQF<=,@QL!
MZ!Q-?Y[ZX*NH<:TI\2?EN@AZ[^:JWUZW=>%N1V_06W&V'Q[]RK&AIW;[<76#
M@!FL!@Y1-XLELV+N+[5E#E:O&QQ'C#NEHJYAN+(;^Q:U/Z1]RQG>!W\=#-&X
MB]?T5D>=F`OT69]=/]9\9[[2N,.P=2W1;]2WY="M2K=59X\?>6.,&@.'KO(X
M8=K'[8^O.@KC!N1OAE5UJW*5PQS;"XC7'*U9ZN(L&BK3#C!N1U35&6LUP\QI
MZ2PF:O@O[Q_4RRU+_:>:=\IY=_2P8.98.RO&6%P<X*>AGH;;C6%>T'3C>+TP
MUZ>3'"#W0^(/OP]T-R-4K[@]PX^F8;X<BKODR#*.Y#1&_I@Y-@%9UO3)88)E
M5B+AQ@#7HQ+FUB&=8@Y:Q=XN_O)OUUSR-%&HM@65-<80ZH=]8JK483=TT*T*
MRSQS"F:&@,+<UZ`9:PF_5@5H,PS,).S9RRLE*]0[],&+799V;)#?.==",B<W
M>N&,2[<,*,*Z^=_<\LL\P_2.WTR7L[T-;=:%,KTZL+?VT5E=P9;[[F7#32G%
M#-..KR;$X5JO]G5N;<BSS?#)30LC=.9'7LZMXKTRL\]??M3N\W+E2FV5IS$K
M^9P%EN@>,:[WKQ#PSC6P:SD6RM9S"-F.L1E:%JVM:]X]:MK6%B,5=@7>(W,5
MG8583.89*6=YJSF9=#&S&ZN672+1!K%BCCB\PC,CB"XQ=<LBF\'(W"0Q%9W\
M*OPL;!,&G<Y?39)Q,P;.XIL62F`XJ_YS.*'C7)5H#C*8#S%T5B,586#%G-:R
MLQ]"S6<SL]YJX3(T6'8X?.,.F8,]AA[)97X"P\SZNW[FES=Y:.?2?HWDUD#D
M+CSQYE5@W9J+KG_)\V_PNVN%>#<DW5_'<;']BW[K5_ZMP+K[EC)1T%B/:G%5
M<L7'U9XX)A-W7)O!C,/Y!F%8#!65@ELKAK&<.PJ=W5QLSS):\VBU.LPQQPPL
M&6<2/&/&.U.Q;2>YI\F[G7>[O;^E\2]U;.FS&Q?EF`]HPMXP=+<Y<"S.2JP/
M&*L,6*.$6'I<7J*O859$<.N\*QI71RV3=O^6#IF8Q:MBQ?K#PW?F1Q.JW\=A
MYRK65>Q4TGU3</_UX;2\6M[=:S-]5OGW:[@UK*R/97>YBKN#%O69S]IPU6\K
M&ILA:$Z.F1]JK`?"82KA&`W`P5F856F.#&-5A*P4R3!6LPF>8#O(]</4C)%E
M;Q@Q&XIW4<_6F/4C6LXT&-;9D&-V%DO.7[=GLR[1<-9%J6+Y)BZ4W]E:EB<A
M:C.K09:\'8*T1A5;)@,&#6FDY%LQEF5UK.R*P8,DSL6HT'TF1G8,&!69E8,[
M(Q81B87F]VRIXT]WUY<-J<>7'6I=R?J7_'-/%O_;W+_2Z!TSAKN+<-*FWK@I
MBKQ+D6-/1L%\MA=S?1G&CB1W-FE>,K"<&,+P8V3(,*=36Q9G]%T8R3N4]/3,
MPF%[YHSHWAKY8]RSCIK=LS)4_);%G?M,Z.AJQ!]`Q>26+YQMBRDYMBXJ,+FU
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MA_$/JCQP\R/LCW`^6/8#KAZH?N#]P?^#QP_P'NA\8?4'\8]8/0CW`\Z.R'9C
MWH]@/1#VX^(/]Q^(>5E_9+]ZGY2=NG;IVZ?G)[)/SD_L3V:?'3ZZ?-3OD^$G
M^"?#3YZ>$G^:>"GN4_E3^1.]3^=/JI_Y3X:>_3O4[Q/#3PT^6GPT[Q/>)X:=
M^GP4_83_%/#3X:?^$^$GQ4^HG]2=^G]2>$G]*?&3^%/ZD_\)_Z3ZB?43^E/J
M)]9/DI\]/!3["?(3YB?YI]5/JI_>G_E/DI\A._3Z"?+3_-/II_*GTD^NG^*?
M23^A/`3P4_K3Z2?93^]/Z$\1/Z4\-/M)XB?:3[2?13^U/I)]%/MIXB?:3PD^
MDGUT^FGU$^HGW$^JG^*?63[:?:3[:?:3["?;3[9?IE^J7ZI?R3]3[P_1/^AD
M>!=^?IAR'>,,-"O.#"OTCV;\\_#6H7Z1]D9+6:(S#W+"FQI@CI&48DP'+W_0
MXY_E3Y3BKAW=9GKM!IO6O5M!Q#PC\3]0P*[2ML/U-.GZ!R8_(-"&YIFG`NT:
MC(TAVC_V9!H,*VTPOQC(.%<K\R^9<2Z-Y9X4:;CZ=8/DO`/,NY.WM!^:OU.(
MOU/_Y_+/P#9J]G7^S37,#9LTR-W3"N/O".XSNSI6T=16VN[W+N(5QHU57`CI
MN6'Z&4;.Z+NW-OE693]]Y^_$_`^I>_<`T+\PY9KC>W2#EQPE-!VP85M1PX_,
M.D=UK\`SN-&$TW]LQF+!@P8,6-62Q']C$>_?E:L^$_4:%\2,\Y.\HM>W9QMJ
M648$[LK(K;TW`]J-JSUL;E:8N`&GP#Q]EN8<L[*Z*GZ1QXX)N9TE^BTVX;YC
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MP6FPIH,3&F+"IS=MABN`81;$9!C0T6%6FQ5BQ4&3%6&)3#"4PQ2,,*1@P586
M*"^'8D3TD8J#Z-6!0SV$IMS"H.RCUBR(O/X)QE@)Q+"4_/6%2V;"A[M8%6O5
MA._R0ZA@XM1]R/%+AU9JO/69P+]=TH_7G@&I-=W]ICY]MWS7\+UCL7LW3.+8
ML6+?L7`T[NZ]7_L[R[XT*W:NOG@>X.LG!-FK_&:;)?EGL!D?;:#G&R=@]4WK
MEG<VE/UIW-IL&1XUE9&B\?,S.^Q/L/1S69F>9IH-)N7Z)[CD7H!K.;NZ5M%J
M]"/X9X?P+TCAW.3@6V;5P`\@-P]3?6>)&5]V_ZKO\W5VJG%JT'<L9PV#+/CW
M0CM<\/]OZ--[:#1=0,(Z].)?_R??1F?JW@VBT--4Z*,1K%A'(W26"R+REA.+
MX-I7Q/UM#PC"^15HNJN,6==KG%/O,C83FAPSC9S3>,[Q+C!MWG973VYL[9TQ
M96+M5@/$L7JV+/&*NPMS>5LSBF#K&=DQ,*\Z]BQIN9STXN>CF,Q9:;F8,)_J
MV3B73.]SOD[U:*W%-F,9LFT]`RPV\_`.@'<AH*S-%6><@R5IC8#,.%EEOSCH
M!E&FT"]9)L/<1H7;V99+6SK--)9[*P7.F%U)V]E5HMPLKJES!;:K6N4OO7%F
M'^1YMAZ1]\^N]W86%VMU-KJN)'3M>5U4P5M)M:>#Q>A&B^\X5[RY`<-;"83A
M7N5:-\\<S*VC<-E/43PDT%?G6Z+VI^R]\MNTQX7)W\=746=#I7$<TL%Z];F;
M&W4ZR9Z=5.`&,TV`_WF)-C-29ID5SRNX,KT>65PCB*8TTVZID>;F^'03(.XM
M![9YD:LXX:E9GA7;INQJ/`-K6=+8TY28C_7!ZJ\]=(-X,M-C-U<#.4:E-Q,]
MVG_W@A_9IZPX2T'BG'K)<NRMP_['38U]RV-/UFRFA-!Y]IWTGJ]%ZZ>U<K.(
M&G<I85_3:;T$X9;>;FO`3\+&;Z>.FG:$PFK.$G:.4=P9I6UI[]RBO&W#YAWM
MA."O)N^\XTZUGC[:7:Z_4Y=UC5G,3!-*GQ!VD[U.\SP2^-<WG7:+7:]@;FR/
M<75U>R?I/TGG>K71+[Q<ZW=Y*MA62[1R+S(V+K7'M!^*V=/\K5I\AX.=SG&O
M'_M4GDYTMHM>O3U[WM5S"T6"\?6SK1.%;J\`//#TPYL<R5RCSS9/V![=T5,C
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M`__.-L8R#^VV=^Z]?.[C/;.]&,ED:*JQ;099N9P$X>ME:-\7Q/EWDKEKVCM[
M3T9Z)S3<O,ORO!-PW%N%;YNU:DR-R/X'X+V]P$Y^=A-.X"]X\'/TNM&P7;]>
M=X?0<,_';:VHZ=X::8U[Y?^_89YRU]EKSE':ZXRZ!5:LK">,F`N%ME;)Q"L!
ML!J/6,)U8\36`[S/G]4-Q6+T+Y;93UMU.H5^T]GC/$7_K%]T>"N4--U+P*MP
M/'V:\G/+7[EJ7RNQ[*R7!/@/29'I+[SVMC9)6NUE8MDV2LH[>W/$U\WI>&5.
MKF#.TW=.W8VF\,Q>(5L)Y&X]G&:ZF>0G\^G<3>;;R'T=]?,?RSRC9-E-<;]X
MMLGTG?U=K9',#L6(Z]5NIB\:V@T&J/<7@K7M!J,%7A!T->0G0N\LU7&L6H.V
MU_T_Q<]=PW3OC\+E!XH>ZT+Y,KM+8H[Q?L#95D5LAT6-HV$_>:4XEDLU,C->
MAK*.'&Y'CK]%^F\7:[<-NV)RJX2.`YAQ[TC]I[*?=NU:]KKBKNK=UBQ5K-"]
MA.#K+3H!P(QJN)>#5U8R4__,!J,+!O:8L1V\?2R3(\@Q=.UJZ09"O6L"?+FF
MY2TIMQLQGK9C!W*X5MI_C>^O&W(WD;R=QES]\K/;ZPN^/4VK,]KDY9@2M:RN
MP^S-:O'LLSC:C_\ZAE5\EXYBV+M=:,[S.4K)9FFJV=UDT;S+6O7/)M5?9LYO
M<5?W'M64=@L741MJNR?Y.D<PS-+R-70KCK]AN+0=OL.XU;\;]LM-N6([JYAD
M^^NH;JKMD\6.$M89QL]L5VJ[E8WHKC;8V:\(PM_>B>D[(;0<`_4\17[EUCCM
MQ-L/95PUT`SCQ_XZ?:NG<[.>'GAJ#[5Y2QO47(#AZ\36YN_#O_@Z_J<[9+Q;
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MHO$>$6&!O[^&WEO&']2VSC8_4OF/3+ULT!A,%5S0PG@!UE?`8#)*_)?''ENV
MSE!R$Z!_7RM?3?N#-?KWJ+P(SVM.7ZNN4FLYBG'3M*>OV.Y5JM%J`\Y,!+3F
M-;4;6RMH.PM!X2X]FR/]&+^]@TAI69^\Y>ZFZJL]YZ[^/]:\ZYVKL7N-9U;!
MZ"T[B'=O[;DG.+.ON-FK6-Q5KW-1I6V<VUW7OOUU3JCL'B[6MB\;5DN+C4>_
MLS<M]?`MRNQN+JXRX%Z%OF^9V],YUQG.[=`=WW>R<6\!Q;H.K3*[B_$NIMU5
MH3>-T_Z.$]]9S^+O&S'^V_=IICKG75XAK#6LDJT1\AR%\R9:_8N,SS(-C9;4
M:$ZL9Y70-4<TVSMMX+F1L-1QM\Z:CXC(KGF"NJUFL/(MG=NM_QW2O<6P&N]K
M.C<]6J,PW]ZFL7FOTT\7DK;-`?LNAN'NTV%8WU6@K15HCMF+PMY*^+??N\WJ
M*\_-"<X^2X6?2<HW;T@RN'2W$P&TNR8>S8>\8>Y8=\P?F&'PG'5<58,]IM%^
M%?ZKJM2W%;%I#NO^5I.-5E'M'=[S0TWJ9L6$^$Q=0W7>9]5]G5&E=M'X;]8>
M-KU35G`3?7*6O=<QNZZLS6%[FKO);5ZB8N\5<3-:K)/7L&^:#US!DLT]Z7(V
M[>V6+,/IK2O;4V[5MLQ9V%^]9+OZOR'/)]/SBNX*\1-K/FUNG,.(2RCL<H[%
MZ6O=CQ3+=N8-[+VU]=U%./9IL!BQ5GG53<OCV$]DX:7U:N&NSM$U;O+0MBQ9
M.&OU5F#W2SVXL%FO8K*.P',M<MRX`R3QRVK);3B#"P63;JV57?[&,U6W1SH\
MV-SN'.,P_/T3>#8?Q-JSU[E8LR=EO(;A;RGFEZI<&X$:I<<OW;4+87`/<UVO
M;,KCY\-LK8W-;<9KAFS]PQ5SMX)BVBMJV=6HT7%SVLW#_1V#LW@+&>L83YK!
MH6"OO35FP;!YYNIRE7;W!?ZYGVK1FVL)MYNV_>3'`C.UGY7)M*O`7+KXM6S:
MDK=$Q#H(97KR6(ZU74ID\N_+7T.A&=:+/5^]>/="V7D&X#IMTN16%O!REHLC
MA&#!C,9KW=?=M%D+583CV%H5830H^K'/SYMD>5=L;Q5H4YI5F61VYA29ISKR
M(^RO`LK;6JTW(6B^%:5QEJ1AYBR7,C4)LVS:A8M"Q;%M7T&DJ]#:#,T*<%+)
M4Z)N6P:\\4-!_B_95P@_[UK3:%7"N^N0=#9G"N-+Y[C)RE=%,[&?:XMZ2LUA
M,9LU;YD9VT&9D5O9A,;ENMJW]KK;G/&%W_(7.M9QR?&M2Y.]!&BS6$93E&W;
M9W=SS;#D&K.Y/C]33A&NW[BI:-6W97QVSFVI-5HS^!QM6-6WMK-S5V=K.R;)
MU3_)J#7^D_P?,V;BF['`N2G.S75S30;BY.V$99<JPJP7;J\PMXN76NUF$87-
M7/VU#3;X<*Z%-JK7M5PK4N<LK5L])C9:MY7S[H6V=[OC-DX]@X`8/^+2G]S#
M[NV3_&U*OCW@NACC(WD:SB8367P[D^^6C9IX.O"S\LVK7&^FA-LX5C/F--C:
MTN(=!+-346!@M2S6K:B\;93,O*70KZ-AY]68CAIS5K.:F1PMT;U=L'-/C6N]
MKLIN!QS;TF9TS;M\RCBU[^,0T*<LG\5[VUEK70K):D<M>R->["V+L]"T+"P?
M@QGBKEF<9%;&8*SM\[7E?>9:;>9V:[A5P\\LVCSBM-6DT7G6%W.PF0M@/0\!
M>UNMN@>GN?MC.)<;.XMR.!?M^([PXN<+-*=RTW)S"X*N-BU*/)`<:=>L297M
M'"LUT4;(:ZLJM*K3L)USPCFRU')N`=@YJU9IJS392NU-5BPF=L)U=Q[<..MT
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MTAH3,P;MIS(V3C1TK\M;A\/_B\`]E6P;VM2;>^[:\W+)S5O'"C0=SL[/-JYA
M\EN629:FI<6LAGLX;^P6A,X^9F;FPK-;:-*^!OEX;R0X3<#6&O:[)U%P[.[?
M0/%,5?`6\96HTYM&G'`3.XRPJP;%@]3.OM9:\Y6KXVS:LV->4G_SPU=M?FN&
M?%PGTKB!R@R.:;K%TG;8[K.`<$YF-XVK?V,__<3.\CN_?KW_[]SKX#^U^BG/
M-T-_'>Z_@9)[$<\WUFN2<W86[CF79+DOGW4N:/:NY79JMJ^+3:#X'1/JLPSC
MAYL9]"=G5]E_%>GO@VB.2>U5]1Y)A/%4[J^\_N>,;-NZ8-HXE];=#X#[MH#F
MYEC>KADMTJRY*V*.HL+B6&(]LM[&\-KV&SO4UTUI7..V6LZU@.D?X5M1HS).
M58-0:33:;L\M9)T*L*L&+AF$_[9&^O5U6[&L.T:D[.TIP-;1[ER$_QO`6VKN
MFA.,JO(OG#ODV#Q-LAZB\D-DJ_)T@[PSCGZ?5OYZZ]YZVWR7K_1CQ=^>U!KM
MX]C<UVWTKND\D_!7CAIRXM^:MQ,%-M=E=5\G(\1PW1-_;9^SD5C.3G_.O+O(
M[Q[&OL=9Z6OGWP^>ZH;P:U=<.>=C+^MC/20S7SY[*?:?9>,GQGLQSTSLS_\^
M<^@^N\Y.=KE7[KK)LG$TV=N*W0XR?0:;N#2;5_XV#2'UYI39--]N=D[M.Q>*
MG`3PEY=[UPSEVQ>0;U_JX!RTXZR=LN6N`N8M)<(L(PC@L4LHPC@UZP]/9K0C
M0+7JU[\986%B,+%FC8+\I;-#-5A&E:#\FZ-/5U:MJ1I6HR1F1A'Y%6<L]+,6
M$;XOG,D=I5S)EDOJ=%IM,9ZOGS1L;EQA6+,YG)#&Z:G--XUYM:VDM6M8:C^:
M_D^OJM9]]Y^:$[X-6M661+[["ON.5;)U;?W,CP+0E?!'DYY%X:F6:U:TN59G
M\E;AE'9UGK&72V3V3Z7PQQL\4.]#L;7;!L)I=%=[ZZX7NZO8G$J[JY]>U;2]
M3BVPVR=&-:G`USK[%H/ZAV(]U.NM.7D7'\6-%K.TQ+T579SY`X,?/',C/;F6
M$L;[+`9+6EWQXV_P^;/[NN](-1_;LMGVRO]QDNVO<S7EHS?O1\Y;R^!?>T)?
M]WI'*>";']OQ>7>[>LNBN9ME-4'QOJWS?O+]=]2KKK4'*4TI>Z^;RK7'AK0E
M9Y=;:(PL!V<RS++Y%NN6F>9G*>D=MY`>5?1;<?C&S&]'-6%>X&_G^E=S<@\0
MXRMQ+:7#5Y`=H/J=?PGC)SZNZNQA[-Z9JLBCHIBQE:TNX#)/O5P$V[W=>RKL
M_D>XT;O_P&Z;1K2TKSFA3LKN%FE\?A'JZ_']WEVE30E@WOT*X!QCDOJ#?-!X
M"^`.K>4GRQIS82\53BQ\WVKMUJOF>NL1P$\'+V&RGN]A+?CF[AFDRRW;%[B7
MO;VX_?'$M!_,?>WO$]I>NJ]/\MR*U;TR[1D>]XI/!3T3N3OCV;\[OSH:ZK^A
M_A<C7>?_?2S9*\7-].(MI+OP^VYJNL':Z[?6>6>>:<(/@CZ4V6NT7)/*-.7\
M3WN<;-R+$>8GYO\^5M[F?0M27KND'X_<U^LZVNEO_"M&6G'L*N8<H.KSJ:$]
M=97Y6'YGXOQW:'TH\)TY_Q-@O^'^HYBNG>HKC__?P/)/..PND&K+W=@[_;A^
M+P`_Y_W?Z^]7@+]=N-A/#/I[-X5^WDMJ]X:B=C:I/37FS4OV!_X/_J\6-;LF
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MW?7QK\S;/Z[1E\Q;V?1=U>EY'[[I[A)\!M*?79)@KN`];7++*..&9L9>!<0.
MM?V-!X3K;I*^*\"Y>Q?L#U]V5M9Y.V,O%C8O,CO==<]M)HW_G4/>WVK4E_O9
M[W:Y"QL@ZL8LTMK/RWQG)#YP__AGE_[M/;/77,?];!VE?N=17[[MD.3'P::T
MO7Z5</TGQ!SPRWB!ZNN3'@[=C4E[(>W]#S+_K477]?;CP\^$,%:E.G;2Y$N9
MNX.Z\@\"\KY6KR#5;=XQSK_<^4^*\>NGN6L3[`QG4#M=E</P[7G!#(XQY5X1
MZMZ)_6ZF>'F$X2?PVVCV_>KMK@.2Z*KI6Z?N:KT-QG7N-NK/TXW*<`N>M1LI
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MK#X+?W@O`M6T+QCEVNGKZOGNN&*/<G^2^RW5R;>OXFG+\KW>N/KV`TK"FC:-
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M"Z:X9_R/Z.U-(=Z8-8>CGPZ:]_JCEZMXM2GJ+`_RMTGON++T/S[]+PAJCLE_
MSKWS@65R8P+5EN\O2:UEE\=S][GU7-/ZJX7_[>W3C3E[)[J_E\T\'7;'0OOV
M0;A7(-.6J]AT@ZSF?$7ZSX+_AZ5S+\S65_RUI:4_`WM^!]QSC1_C:,L]\P:[
MZSC[GW&RUD(0)TSMKFA^S9W]Q;29%IN?O<,C)/BX3F&#VN6?R,$O@,%96#HY
MO+(KH9]M?!<XT)WI6QEN7K77OR]WKD.D\I]C+..;)<I873#82XRX"NY>BGI+
M:OVAWB]Z/\'%O)=;6]:TN]M-P'ZK[`^C-LO`RL%G<*ZV5=1#`>TG)W&5PHT%
M\QI1TPTQBV0_O'QYTK"92:-,)L'A7-N5<36<N;6LV$S&LF%GMS96%A)F*RJQ
M%8CY58$<W@RS`=8Q'2C:C$8CP8U!^1H77C\P_,-_-8:<SL7T!NX9&@,!HUJ#
M0L7CAE)K#G;3*LEA8+/;%D)5T5T#R[VS_E_8[XT*=P>IL8U6!/^)@*MVK-9%
M@*WJPO_\Q05DF4UF8#]?X`,"6_______^]O_O_^____?____W^O________[
M_____O_M=?]`%_@``*1`!-`T)4HIH:-E!Z&DS*-&@:::-&C(]!`T&0,09#(`
M,F30R8('J&1H8(,@#)H&0TQJ:9&@T:&0&1IIHT9'J/49`S*"J@`!H``#0```
M``````&C0```R&@``````````````````"`````````#0`T```````-`#0T:
M``T``````9`````-``!HR:!`````````!H`:```````&@!H:-``:``````,@
M````&@``T9-`%4230C2:>I-DFT:"3U/)J;4_)1L1E&C0V*8T1XD;4'J'B@Q&
MFC(\H!Z(>H-/4&@:9!ZCRCTGJ#RCT-3U,F)M(?JAY1^I/34/%`:`>IY0TU:%
M'6MDL(>K;%4[`]HJ;%8=:^XZ%<;]#8(6E:&;.L,BN*CF)6%2\=>T;2NG=4V"
MRB,TS;.,PS*M"M185JU:$:5&&DR3<<:M"RLE;:H3$!@(3$0CZ'V*"&/O*(B*
MT@@X4Q!$0B+V9F('IY1"(0B$1#N?*BR21?(2,`2BA!*4$=&D(2E$6U"72%%1
M)$B4HS")5&91Y119:M*B&(AKEQ;B%AGUQ#4(CGEX\VE;77+5&A7I;)1TPVZ\
M9Q+I5MD4,BRC&=PNL\LPE*(@0`BTE$$1H4P#PTHB(YM+.I+"I2&Z448RBA$0
MA`$>%(BVB8A`V<CI]5JIGIIFJEC]4GG)<61]N1!`!%2)+Y111<5**DI2E4D5
M)%1I%A0J&XYWME2(/V.HHB(3*93'8RX\U):I$POD."Y;%<%:$'STD/,8]%MU
M;FEQ80:?#LK*PC4<T4&CWOI>K0\)6-_HZ/NRW>09I4H4*)(E%&P4B.[J750R
M[!>(^U81F_=VUMJ7@+*/(E':[!#"W`7C"P_-,/_&F9I:76"\!^FZ_1X[V52.
MT7:(;[DALW#L-HW^!1,PE=INMS^NTR:&@1#!*)\65&UQ;,0_=V7":7>UNXYF
M_[OOM)?L\A^_0IX?M$9Y.56++7?V"PT<T.!.NSYL5:W3T$[/6TN;`PC8"$*1
M('>&\?<^Y/;8\UM#O+QC>HHL)+YK5$6D/;2='T7.UD1:6G'X'SNBT&LO\@WO
M:]14W,MW['KLDR23C2AV;^[C8^R8)_#?>Z?A=]JR84%2E.%,D/:C6G:8FG*J
M+Z/::$PG-Y+;10>GR#^D';T78^3TW$U[)A6G#;9M*)FOI)RQ9)3$*G&`[DG2
M9-U$)J3G$1IFD(%3;V#TZ&19]T3V4*.'?M0-&N)!Y9VD;^;2KZ&..*,%_GZR
M885X@2NF`'B&$ISNYVK.MEJ=@/Q,9^9\/Q]!P/0:?;8O'X'EL=J6O:)1Q7@N
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M1WYKO),HT/?UKNG"];0-R[G4[;;\LOD=EK^#S-PW1`U%1/5$Q8X+@%PE/5?6
M;P#C>JHD[V(+T('0Z)"/$4KTEUB7."([Q1M%X8./<XM4PS?\T[+F5-_)$8:^
MU$%[OU!"'($#^^V-2]_:RV)`:1JBW%PE60%)H&P`;0@(ZW#OG>%7SG)BN8'T
M!;">34B+7J[`S@>@"\..!44,;*8`RY\$8(SC5-F9#34/OI!B\:I=-7@G2V./
M#6P!"I!!T#_'5MW>1P91P6AH1C\]$P&LAB'%YLSQ'Y,474_)7XL1)B#5B#QQ
M7DT2Z!,[1_WEKV5HHG$BQ5R*M2(F9N^QEXF5=\'+,-HAK85$I2K8,EY)E<IL
MX=P;>)LI\>H.+NC=<C`&Y=>":R[M.I8E%8NU:_'^YZM=)T6ZM'<J(6\V'+B%
M+Q63*_L5V:Q!A36]`[H!8+%LY7&T[+^/.C$8DMTH/KY)$_3#%^],JVC93%<3
MJXCE!QPC]],'E?*(;1W6$I<UQ]9R*6UBTD)!4.5/+B!.G(>$[?[V6X&9H>+M
LLM[AY#D[ZUR)(B(A!Z240B$(A$0TG\_Y8'/W[S)5O<;_Q=R13A0D"R.)7H``
`
end
``````````````````````````````````````

Now, I'm not sure what good it's going to be to you without you being able to inspect its content with zfs commands.

You can find small VM images for Linux or FreeBSD with which you can create all sorts of zpool configurations.

Comment: Thanks.  I converted the uuencoded text and found it contained a .7z compressed file, correct ?  Unpacked it resulted in a 64 MB file, which seems to correspond with your commands.  I however could not find the superblock I was hoping to find ( based on these signatures: https://github.com/travisg/newos/blob/master/kernel/addons/fs/zfs/zfs_fs.h )  Maybe I'm missing something entirely

Comment: PS. does it have file(s) inside ?  A small jpg or txt file or something ?

Comment: @Peter, No, no file, it's really been created as shown.

Comment: I don't know what that zfs source code of yours comes from, but it doesn't seem to bear much resemblance with the real ZFS. Check [there](http://open-zfs.org/wiki/Main_Page) for the source code on the various OSes where it's supported. The [grub code for zfs](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/grub-core/fs/zfs) ([includes](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/include/grub/zfs)) may be more accessible.

Comment: I'm getting the impression as well, that I'm looking at wrong defines.  I found following with an ubercode magic number that I can actually *find* in the sent image file: https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/blob/master/include/sys/uberblock_impl.h

Comment: I implemented recognition based on the ubercode magic number.  All seems to work properly.  Thanks.  As version I find 5000.  To make recognition a bit stricter (avoid false positives), is there a minimum version and/or maximum version I can check for ?  For instance version cannot be 0 ?

Comment: @Peter: Version 5000 is specifically the OpenZFS version for post-OpenSolaris implementations of ZFS. Solaris ZFS exists in version numbers from 1 to 35 at present. All non-Oracle Solaris ZFS uses 28 or lower, or 5000.
I very much doubt you will ever come across false positives if you are searching for the correct uberblock magic (0000000000bab10c) but if you're anal you could also validate the uberblock checksum.